# Pivot a Two Column DataFrame With No Numeric Column To Aggregate On

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe with input like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
     {'StoreId':
           [244, 391, 246, 246, 130, 130] , 'PackageStatus': ['IN TRANSIT','IN TRANSIT','IN TRANSIT', 'IN TRANSIT','IN TRANSIT','COLLECTED',]}   
    )

        StoreId     PackageStatus
0           244        IN TRANSIT
1           391        IN TRANSIT
2           246        IN TRANSIT
3           246        IN TRANSIT
4           130        IN TRANSIT
5           130        COLLECTED
```

The output I'm expecting is to look like this with the package status pivoting to columns and their counts becoming the values:

```
StoreId     IN TRANSIT       COLLECTED
244         1                0
391         1                0
246         2                0 
130         1                1
```

All the examples I come across are with a third numeric column with which some aggregation (sum, mean, average etc) is done.

When I tried

```
 df1.pivot_table(index='StoreId',values='PackageStatus', aggfunc='count')
```

I get the following instead:

```
              PackageStatus
StoreId               
130                       2
244                       1
246                       2
391                       1
```

In my case I need a simple transpose/pivot with the count. How to accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `columns="PackageStatus"` parameter:

```
print(
    df1.pivot_table(
        index="StoreId", columns="PackageStatus", aggfunc="size", fill_value=0
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
PackageStatus  COLLECTED  IN TRANSIT
StoreId                             
130                    1           1
244                    0           1
246                    0           2
391                    0           1
```

---

With `.reset_index()`:

```
print(
    df1.pivot_table(
        index="StoreId", columns="PackageStatus", aggfunc="size", fill_value=0
    )
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis("", axis=1)
)
```

Prints:

```
   StoreId  COLLECTED  IN TRANSIT
0      130          1           1
1      244          0           1
2      246          0           2
3      391          0           1
```

Comment: The solution with `.reset_index()` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the extremely fast response. Unbelievably fast.

Comment: Could you help understand what `rename_axis()` does in the context of this example?

Comment: @FMFF Without `.rename_axis()` you will have text "PackageStatus" over the index. With `.rename_axis("", axis=1)` I just clear it (you can ommit this step if you want).

Comment: No, that is exactly what I wanted. I will keep it. Thank you again.